# Error imprimiendo la fecha actual en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Esta es la consulta que me está mosqueando, porque está dando error:

```
INSERT INTO tratamientos ("Tratamiento 1", "Tratamiento 2", "Tratamiento 3", "Tratamiento 4", "Tratamiento 5", "paciente", "fecha") VALUES ('0','1','0','1','0','Rex López Sánchez',CURRENT_DATE())
```

Esta es la estructura de la tabla:
[image: Estructura de la tabla tratamientos]

Comment: que error te marca?

Comment: No especifica el error en sí

Comment: ¿Cómo que no especifica el error? ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado y cuál el obtenido?

Comment: para los campos date, simpre se utiliza el default value `now()`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***NOTA**: Edito la respuesta, y añado lo correspondiente a MySQL (había puesto referencias a SQLServer).*

***Para MySQL:***

Para MySQL pudes probar con `NOW()`. O si sólo quieres la fecha con `CURDATE()`.

```
INSERT INTO tratamientos ("Tratamiento 1", "Tratamiento 2", 
"Tratamiento 3", "Tratamiento 4", "Tratamiento 5", "paciente", "fecha") 
VALUES ('0','1','0','1','0','Rex López Sánchez',NOW())
```

Puedes revisar también otras funciones como:

- NOW()  -> Fecha y hora actual
- CURDATE()  -> Fecha actual
- CURTIME()  -> Hora actual
- DATE(NOW()) -> Extrae la fecha de un campo Fecha/Hora
- TIME(NOW())  -> Extrae la hora de un campo Fecha/Hora

Puedes probar con una sentencia como esta, para verlas en funcionamiento:

```
SELECT NOW(), CURDATE(), CURTIME(), DATE(NOW()), TIME(NOW())
```

=============================================================

***Para SQLServer:***

Prueba con la función `GETDATE()`.

```
 INSERT INTO tratamientos ("Tratamiento 1", "Tratamiento 2", "Tratamiento 3",
 "Tratamiento 4", "Tratamiento 5", "paciente", "fecha") 
 VALUES ('0','1','0','1','0','Rex López Sánchez',GETDATE())
```

Como comentarios adicionales, yo utilizaría para el campo **PACIENTE** un `NVARCHAR(_longitud_)`, según los datos que parece que vas a introducir.

Revisa también ayuda sobre estas otras funciones de date/time:

- CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
- GETDATE()
- SYSDATETIME()
- CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
- GETUTCDATE(),
- SYSUTCDATETIME(),
- SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()

Puedes probar una SQL como esta para verlos en funcionamiento:

```
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, GETDATE(), 
       SYSDATETIME(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, GETUTCDATE(),
       SYSUTCDATETIME(), SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
```

Comment: Esas son funciones de SQL Server y la pregunta es para MySQL.

Comment: Perdón, no había visto el TAG, me he quedado con el "SQL" y me ha confundido. Corrijo la respuesta.